# Which path to use for Kyngchaos Postgres?

Tags: macos, postgresql

I am setting up a new Macbook with OSX Yosemite from scratch.

I want to install and use the [KyngChaos](http://www.kyngchaos.com/software/postgres) versions of Postgres, rather than the system version of Postgres. I have [downloaded the KyngChaos packages](http://www.kyngchaos.com/software/postgres) and installed them, without any errors appearing.

However, when I run `psql` there is nothing on my path.

If I run `find` it looks as though there are now two Postgres's on the machine, in these directories:

```
/usr/local/pgsql-9.3/bin/psql
/usr/local/pgsql/bin/psql
```

So my questions:

1. Which one is the KyngChaos package and which is system Postgres?
2. How should I remove the system Postgres?
3. How should I set my path to use the KyngChaos package?

Comment: Just got the answer to (1) from https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/contrib/gis/install/#kyngchaos - the version at `/usr/local/pgsql/bin/psql` is the Kyngchaos one, and you can set it in your `~/bash_profile`.

Comment: So my only remaining question is really: should I do `rm -rf /usr/local/pgsql-9.3` in order to remove the system postgres?

Comment: ! No, I think the answer to (1) is actually `/usr/local/pgsql-9.3/bin/psql`, judging from a line in one of the KyngChaos READMEs. I'd still really like to know the definitive answer.